# ViewNavigator inside a view

Tags: performance, apache-flex, memory, mobile, view

I was playing with my flex mobile and i could see that im able to add multiple **viewnavigators** inside a view. This would mean that each **viewnavigator** will have its own navigator stack and would be able to do push and pop at its level. Is this a good design? Can this affect the performance. Will it prevent my the view(which contains the view navigators) from being destroyed once i move out of it.
The code looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home Page" >

    <s:ViewNavigator left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="92%" firstView="headerView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator left="0" right="75%" top="8%" bottom="0"  firstView="middleView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator left="25%" right="0" top="8%" bottom="0" firstView="rightView"/>

</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what Adobe's [TabbedViewNavigator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS77c1dbb1bd80d383527e1a6412a8a5d909a-8000.html) does, so it can't be that bad ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use this on your Application (ViewNavigatorApplication or other):

```
persistNavigatorState="true"
```